# Titan order by ES indexed vertex property?

Tags: titan

Per the latest Titan 0.4.1 [docs](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Indexing-Backend-Overview#ordering), this code should work to order vertices in a result set:

```
graph.query().has("name",CONTAINS,"john").orderBy("age",Order.DESC).limit(10).vertices()
```

I would like to perform this type of query across a potentially large set of vertices, and thus would like to index it.  The docs suggest:

> Most external indexing backends support ordering natively and
>   efficiently. However, the property key used in the orderBy method must
>   be configured to be indexed in this indexing backend for native result
>   ordering support. This is important in cases where the orderBy key is
>   different from the query keys. If the property key is not indexed,
>   then sorting requires loading all results into memory.

Specifically for the Elasticsearch backend, how can we create an index that will support this `orderBy` method?

Is there a simple 3rd parameter to pass to the `KeyMaker`'s [`indexed`](http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/javadoc/current/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/KeyMaker.html#indexed%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.Parameter...%29) method, possibly an extension to the below example from the [docs](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Indexing-Backend-Overview#indexing-vertices-and-edges)?

```
graph.makeKey("age").dataType(Integer.class).indexed("search", Vertex.class).make();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to index the property in ES (like any other property).

Indexed in Titan (wrong; orderBy will not be optimized):

```
graph.makeKey("age").dataType(Integer.class).indexed(Vertex.class).make();
```

Indexed in ES (correct; native result ordering in ES):

```
graph.makeKey("age").dataType(Integer.class).indexed("search", Vertex.class).make();
```

Cheeers,
Daniel

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your quick reply.  So, I've tried running the following query after creating the ES index on `age` (using your second example above): `g.query().orderBy("age", Order.DESC).vertices()`.  That results in the warning: `...Query requires iterating over all vertices...`.  Should I be using a different query syntax?  Or is there another step required to have titan use ES for the sort?

Comment: Oh, you really want to query ALL vertices? Depending on how large your graph is, this will be a super expensive operation. The first query (`graph.query().has("name",CONTAINS,"john").orderBy("age",Order.DESC).limit(10).vertices()`) should work just fine with the given type definition (but the filter condition is important, otherwise you wouldn't need ES to sort your result).

Comment: To add: make sure both "age" and "name" are indexed in ES and that you have some sort of restrictive condition - otherwise you are going over the entire graph since sort orders aren't pre-computed.